# Colour repeated rows by groups in Excel

Tags: excel, colors, repeat

I have a table like this one:

| Column 1 |
| --- |
| 111 |
| 111 |
| 100 |
| 100 |
| 100 |
| XX6 |
| XX6 |
| L1 |
| PPP |
| PPP |

And I would like to colour it in just two colours (colour 1 and colour 2) in a way that the repeated rows are easy two distinguish, so for example the rows with 111 would be colored in colour 1, 100 in colour 2, colour XX6 in colour 1, L1 in colour 2 and so on.

There are more columns in the real table, but this one is the key to make this.

Is there a way to do that in Excel?

Comment: Create the helper column as mentioned in the Solution link and then apply two rules in conditional formatting, one for the color 1 `=AND(LEN($A2)>0,MOD($B2,2)=1)
` and for the color 2 `=AND(LEN($A2)>0,MOD($B2,2)=0)`  . Assuming you have the list range in column A and the helper column will be in column B

Comment: Thanks, it worked. How I refer the solution from here?

Comment: So do you want me to post the solution in answers again considering your data list

Comment: No no, it's not necessary, I mean, how I can close the question and refer the solution to the other question you have linked?

Comment: Yeah check now, since it worked for you, you can accept the same as answer/upvote!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Conditional Formatting By Group With Two Colors

Here's how you can conditionally format by groups

• In cell `B1` (same row as the header) enter `Helper`,

• In cell `B2` enter the below formula,

```
=IF(A2=A1,B1,N(B1)+1)
```

• Select the data range, as shown in image below `A2:A11`,

• Press ALT `H` + `L` + `N` to show the New Formatting Rule dialog box

• Now enter a new rule formula — use a formula to determine which cells to format — with the below formula

```
=AND(LEN($A2)>0,MOD($B2,2)=1)
```

• Click the Format button --> Fill Tab --> Choose desired color --> Press Ok.

Repeat from the **Bullet Point 3** for the **Color 2** and enter the below formula

```
=AND(LEN($A2)>0,MOD($B2,2)=0)
```

**Side Note:** Hide the **column (column B)** where you have the formula.

[image: CONDITIONAL_FORMATTING]